# fileLength = 0 When trying to Download PDF File from Database

Tags: java, oracle, file, servlets

fileLength = 0
File Reading Success
getting file Length as null  when trying to download pdf file from DATABASE.
    Actually have to get Some PDF File which has Some content that was stored in local database 
    Would You Please Help Me on this Particular ISSue , What should do now  to resolve this problem and file was uploaded through Client Side Program Only

```
        public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet {

          private static final int  BUFFER_SIZE = 40960;


        protected void doGet(--){

            String bookId = request.getParameter("bookId");


            Connection conn=null;
            try {

                 Class.forName("--");

                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("--");

                String sql="SELECT * from book where bookId=?";
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, bookId);

                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                        if(result.next()) {

                    String bookTitle = result.getString("bookTitle");
                    Blob blob = result.getBlob("bookContent");


                    InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                    int fileLength = inputStream.available();
                    System.out.println("fileLength = " +fileLength);

                    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
                    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(bookTitle);
                    if (mimeType == null) {        
                        mimeType = "application/pdf";
                                       }              

                    System.out.println("File Reading Success");
                    response.setContentType(mimeType);

                    response.setContentLength(fileLength);
                    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; fileName=\"%s\"", bookTitle +".pdf");

                    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);


                    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    outStream.close();             
                }
```

Comment: Without actual database this can not be debugged. + too much source code. You should provide minimal working example which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStream.available()` does not return the file length, but rather the number of bytes which can be read  from the stream without blocking. Most likely the database does not send any bytes of the Blob until you explicitly request the content, and so 0 is returned.

Therefore use

```
int fileLength = blob.length();
```

which gives you the exact length of the file.

Comment: Thank You Its Working Fine And Again Thank You #WERO